# JasperServer CP 4.7 - JBoss and MySQL no certified Support?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

According to the *Support Document* listed below it only certifies *ProsgreSQL* and *Tomcat*, while in Release notes of Community edition they have included support for *JBoss* and *MySQL*.
What is the difference between being certified and being supported in this case?

[JasperServer CP 4.7 Support Document](https://www.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/Jaspersoft%20Platform%20Support%20V4.7.pdf)

[JasperServer CP 4.7 Release Notes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperserver/files/JasperServer/JasperReports%20Server%204.7.0/)

Comment: IMHO, it is better to post such questions on http://jasperforge.org or on http://support.jaspersoft.com

Comment: I have posted the same there as well ;)